# C#: why string cannot be constructed with a string literal as parameter?

Tags: c#, string, constructor, compilation, literals

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    string s = new string("abc"); 
    string s2 = "abc"; 
}
```

Well this program has compiling error in first line, the string constructor cannot accept a string literal, while the 2nd line compiles OK.

So what's the difference between line 1 and line 2, I suppose they're both constructors, why 1st line has compilation error?

Comment: Well, there is no matching constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.aspx  `"I suppose they're both constructors"` - No, only the first line uses a constructor.  The second line simply assigns a value.

Comment: Since you've obviously read documentation before asking the question and found that there is no matching constructor... Please clarify what exactly you are looking for as an answer? Historical information why it done that way? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# string constructor only accept these arguments which string is not one of them:

```
unsafe public String(char*);
       public String(char[]);
unsafe public String(sbyte*);
       public String(char, int);
unsafe public String(char*, int, int);
       public String(char[], int, int);
unsafe public String(sbyte*, int, int);
unsafe public String(sbyte*, int, int, Encoding);
```

http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-constructor